# What determines the search attributes available when creating a smart folder?

Tags: finder, smart-folders

In other words, if I go to Smart Folder > Other... there's a list of search attributes that varies by system, but where do they come from?

[image: "Other" menu]

[image: Search attributes]

Comment: What is "Smart Folder > Other"? Can you perhaps take a screenshot to better illustrate your question?

Comment: Added (my reputation is to low to post an image directly) links

Comment: Your question is still a little unclear — what variation do you see in this list between systems?

Comment: The contents of the list vary per system. E.g. some systems may not have the "Altitude" attribute